# JSONP callback function not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

I have jsonp callback functionalty. Response coming from server is undefined.I do not know where the problem is. I have made RND for jsonp. I am posting code

```
$.ajax({
         url : 'http://192.168.16.111:8081/MiddleWareUsman/androidServlet', 
         type: "GET",
         dataType: "jsonp",         
         crossDomain: true,
         async: false,
         data : {"fname": "chaaaaapiio","lname": "gya"},            
         jsonpCallback:  function(data, status){
            alert('callback');
            alert(data);
         },            
         success: function(data, status){
            alert('sucess');
         },
     error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {          
         alert(thrownError);                        
         }
  });
```

And Servlet code is

```
        String a=request.getParameter("fname");
        String b=request.getParameter("lname");
        String cb=request.getParameter("callback");     
        response.getWriter().write(cb+"("+a+" "+b+")");
```

Comment: Does either your "success" or "error" callbacks get called? I've not heard of `jsonpCallback` being an option that can be used like you are. Note that JSONP requests **cannot** happen synchronously; therefore your `async: false` parameter is moot (per the docs).

Comment: alert('callback');
            alert(data); these are called and error body is also but no secess body

Answer (score 1):

First, `jsonpCallback` is used when you want to override the default function name. If you assign a function to it, then the return value of that function should be the name. Giving it a function that returns `undefined` is just going to break things.

**Remove the `jsonpCallback` property from your object**. Handle things in `success`.

Second, that servlet code is going to generate:

```
jQueryCallback23235(chaaaaapiio gya)
```

This isn't valid JavaScript. You need to have a real JavaScript data structure as your function arguments.

Typically, a JSONP response would consist of an object literal:

```
jQueryCallback23235({ "something": "chaaaaapiio", "something": "gya")
```

Find a Java library for generating JSON and use that to produce the contents of the parens, don't try to write JSON by hand.

Comment: i am not getting your point ..can you please specify in code .. I have researched alot but error calling again and again

Comment: i am not getting servlet side how should i change it?

Comment: Start by finding a Java library for generating JSON.

Comment: if i remove this line   jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback' i get error Jquery was not called